# How to install GDB from another directory?

Tags: c

I'm trying to install GDB on my machine, though I get this error when I run ./configure:

```
configure: error: GDB must be configured and built in a directory separate from its sources.

To do so, create a dedicated directory for your GDB build and invoke
the configure script from that directory:

      $ mkdir build
      $ cd build
      $ <full path to your sources>/gdb-VERSION/configure [etc...]
      $ make
```

So I then created a new directory: /Users/SomeName/SomePath/gdb

And I tried to run the following command:

```
./Users/SomeName/SomePath/gdb/configure
```

But that doesn't work either, I get an error:

```
-bash: ./Users/SomeName/SomePath/gdb/configure: No such file or directory
```

How do I run a C Program from another folder? First time I encountered this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is ` /Users/SomeName/SomePath/gdb` the source folder or the new, empty folder that you just created to build in?

Comment: Is that "." at the beginning of "./Users/..." really supposed to be there? "/Users/..." looks like it's supposed to be an absolute path to me, and unless you're standing in /, "./Users/..." won't be the same thing.

Comment: Please give us the exact sequence of commands that were run leading up to that error. In particular, which directory are you in when running that last command? And you should do some basic debugging. The error tells you there is no file there so explore a bit by trying to list that file or find where it really is.' Finally, `configure` is not a C program.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have stored the gdb sources at `/home/SomeName/gdb-sources` and want to build the gdb in a separate folder like `/home/SomeName/gdb-build` you will need to change to `gdb-build` and call the `configure` Script from `gdb-sources` from within `gdb-build`.

Full example:

```
mkdir /home/SomeName/gdb-build
cd /home/SomeName/gdb-build
/home/SomeName/gdb-sources/configure 
make -j
```